# Why the solutions of Schrödinger hydrogen atom equation do not involve $U$ or $E$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

Please tell me if I am wrong. The general solution to 3D Schr Eq. does not have the terms $U$ or $E$. So the positions of electrons are total independent of the function of potential energy?

$$\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m} \, \nabla \psi=(E-U)\psi$$

Solution:

$$\psi=R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$$

Where

$$Y_{0,0}=\sqrt{1/4\pi}$$
$$R_{1,0}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^3}}e^{-r/a}$$

Thank you. I understand that the spherical symmetry counted. However, many forms of $U$ functions could be spherically symmetric. In this case, $U=-kZe^2/r$ (which is very classic)

If, for example, $U=-Zr$, will the solution be different?

Answer (score 2):

It does involve $E$ and $U$ since the *solutions* to the resulting differential equation depend on $U$ and the boundary conditions related to this $U$ force some discrete values of $E$.

The form $R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$ follows from the rotational symmetry of the potential, which depends only on $r$, but for each $U(r)$ the solutions will give different $R_n(r)$ and possible values $E_n$ associated with these distinct $R_n(r)$.

Answer (score 0):

The separation as a function of $r$ and a function of $\theta , \phi$ is a feature of the specific potential $U$. In the case of the hydrogen atom, the potential is spherically symmetric. The specific information about $U$ namely the charge and the energy $E$ (via the $n$ quantum number ) then goes into the $R(r)$ function. For a more general potential that doesn't have this symmetry, the eigenfunctions would not split like that.